# error while executing scikit-learn program in windows

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, sentiment-analysis

When I execute the following code :

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
 sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\uni.py", line 2, in <module>
          from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in       <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

I am new to Python please help me out on how to resolve it

Comment: How did you install `scikit-learn`? Did you use http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install ?

Comment: No I installed Numpy, Scipy(whl file), Matplotlib, scikit-learn through pip command in command prompt